# Any text before a given text

Tags: python, text-mining, pyparsing

I am wondering how I can formulate any text using pyparsing before a given text that I am looking for. In fact, I have the following code which can found some content if they start by a given header. I have tested the code with an entry that contains only the text I am looking and it works. However when the entrey content contains also other content that doesn't match with the structure that I have defined in pyparsing the code doesn't match the part text that should be match with what I am looking for. 
To be clear this is code the I a using:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pyparsing import ParserElement, LineEnd, Literal, restOfLine,
ZeroOrMore, Group, StringEnd, alphanums,Word,Optional,nums
ParserElement.defaultWhitespaceChars=(" \t")
NL = LineEnd().suppress()
END = StringEnd()
header_1=Literal('******** header_1 ********')
header_2=Literal('******** header_2 ********')
any_header =   (header_1 | header_2)
# text isn't just anything! don't accept header line, and stop at the end of
the input string
text= Group(~any_header + ~END + restOfLine)
overall_structure = ZeroOrMore(Group(any_header +
                                 Group(ZeroOrMore(text))))
overall_structure.ignore(NL)
from pprint import pprint
print(overall_structure.parseString(test).asList())
enter code here
```

When I test the code with the a string "test" like the following one:

```
******** header_1 ********
blabblablbablabal
blablablbalab
******** header_2 ********
blabblablbal
blablbalbal
```

I got a good results and works for me...

However when I add some given text before the old one, like:

```
blablba blabla xvcvchghgs
jhfjdgjshkjmj
jhkfhdsmj:kjkd 
******** header_1 ********
blablablbalab
******** header_2 ********
blabblablbal
blablbalbal
```

In that case, it doesn't work my code whereas it should return the same result that above string...

If I well understood, I have to mention that my text should start with any expression and that I have to skip this content until finding what I am looking for...I tried for more than once to fond how to deal with that but I haven't succeed. Any help please to define an expression that means any content before what I am looking for in pyparsing plaese.